# How to split the data for which every third element goes to test and rest to train in R programming?

Tags: r

EG:

```
df <- c(2,1,4,3,11,9,8)
```

the df can be split into train and test like below

```
train <- c(2,1,3,11,8)
test <- c(4,9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might do.

```
df = data.frame(name = letters[1:10], values = c(1:10))
to_train = seq(3,nrow(df), 3)
df_train = df[seq(3,nrow(df), 3), ]
df_rest = df[setdiff(1:nrow(df), to_train), ]
df_train
#   name values
# 3    c      3
# 6    f      6
# 9    i      9
df_rest
#    name values
# 1     a      1
# 2     b      2
# 4     d      4
# 5     e      5
# 7     g      7
# 8     h      8
# 10    j     10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more options:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(val = c(2,1,4,3,11,9,8))

train <- df[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),]
train
#>     val
#> 1     2
#> 2     1
#> 3     3
#> 4    11
#> 5     8
test <- df[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),]
test
#>     val
#> 1     4
#> 2     9


train2 <- df %>% filter(row_number() %% 3 != 0)
train2
#>     val
#> 1     2
#> 2     1
#> 3     3
#> 4    11
#> 5     8
test2 <- df %>% filter(row_number() %% 3 == 0)
test2
#>     val
#> 1     4
#> 2     9
```

Created on 2018-08-11 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Really nice way of using recycling of vectors in the base R version. This should be the accepted answer, since its much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
  df <- cbind(df, sel =c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
  train <- df[df[,2]==TRUE,1]  
  test <-df[df[,2]==FALSE,1]
```

Comment: 1) This assumes that the original `df` only has one column. 2) `df[,2]==TRUE` is redundant, `df[,2]` alone is *exactly* the same and to test `FALSE` negate it, `!df[,2]`.